# Shared folder, deny user from deleting files

Tags: networking, permissions, directory

I have a shared folder in my network under windows server 2012 r2, I have 1 user that I would like to deny him from deleting any files on the folder.
The problem is that he is part of a group that has access to modify the folder.

Folder 'test' ( network folder )
Group 'Group1' has access to modify / read / write 'test' folder.
The user 'user1' is part of 'Group1', I would like to deny only him from deleting any files, but still have the same network access as 'Group1' and still be able to view the files.

Is it possible?
I don't want to remove him from the group because they have some permissions on this group only.

Comment: It would be nice to know the operating system we are talking about.

Comment: the network folder is under windows server 2012 r2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the **Delete** and **Delete Subfolders and Files** permissions to **Deny** for this user on the folder. This is an explicit permission which will take precedence over the permissions he is inheriting from his group membership. He'll retain all of the other permissions from his group membership.